# How do I make an image act as a upload file button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to make a image act like a button that when pressed it allows me to upload another image.

What I have right now is the part in the snippet but I want to make it pull a image from my server to act as the button and then run some ajax to not have to reload the page then display the image that was chosen (the previous image should change to the one that was chosen).

```css
.Uploadbtn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000066;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Uploadbtn .input-upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Uploadbtn">
  <input type="file" class="input-upload" />
  <span>IMAGE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Suggest a look at this for a sophisticated solution: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="image.jpg" />
```

This is the standard way of using an image in place of a button in an HTML form.

Comment: OP says "...and then run some ajax to not have to reload the page then display the image that was chosen". Maybe the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class='image-upload-btn'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-upload-btn{
    background-image: url('path/to/default.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    //other properties...
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function(){
     var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
     input.type = 'file';
     $('html body').append(input);
     input.click();
})

//after you uploaded new image, you should get an url point to that image,   
//and change the background-image with the new image url
$('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(' + newImageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: I tried it here but wont display image demo: https://jsfiddle.net/atdrw6qr/

Comment: I fixed it, see update https://jsfiddle.net/atdrw6qr/5/

Comment: I've placed the code that is in the snippet like this <script type="text/javascript">
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function(){
     var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
     input.type = 'file';
     input.style.display = 'none'
     $('html body').append(input);
     input.click();
     input.onchange = function(){
         $('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png)');
     }
});

Comment: </script>
<style type="text/css">
.image-upload-btn{
    background-image: url('http://bread.pp.ua/n/settings_g.svg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
<div class='image-upload-btn'></div>

Comment: only the image apears but the on click function does not run. I can't seem to find the problem with this code. Exacly as this two parts of the codes is in my test.php nothing more nothing less. @MarkoCen

Answer (score 0):

You need to just place an Image (set it's source to your image source)and hide the file field.
Whenever someone clicks the Image trigger the click on hidden file_field by javascript.

Then write a javascript method that is called when File_field value changes. 
This method upload files to server and get back the success message along with the newly uploaded image url. Set the Image source to newly uploaded image received from server.

```
<style>
.file_field{
display: none;
}
</style>

 <div class="Uploadbtn">
  <input type="file" class="file_field" />
  <img src="/my_awesome_image.jpg" class='image-field'>
</div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.image-field').click(function(){
   $('.file_field').trigger('click');
})
$('.file_field').change(function(e){
  var files=e.target.files;
  uploadFiles(files,e)});
</script>
function uploadFiles(files,event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit_image_url?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                $('.image_field').attr("src",data.new_source); #Set the newly source returned from server here. It is expecting the server will return the source url in 'new_source' key
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}
```

Follow [This](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) post for detailed file upload through ajax